Starting Android Emulator Throws terminated error
I have installed Android studio, Have also configured Virtualization in windows features, I was able to create any emulator I want with the device manager, but it won't start, upon starting any emulator it throws an error terminated, no log path , no nothing , just emulator is terminated error.
INFO - Emulator: Pixel Fold API VanillaIceCream - C:\Users\chich\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\emulator.exe -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd Pixel_Fold_API_VanillaIceCream -qt-hide-window -grpc-use-token -idle-grpc-timeout 300
INFO - Emulator: Pixel Fold API VanillaIceCream - Android emulator version 35.2.10.0 (build_id 12414864) (CL:N/A)
INFO - Emulator: Pixel Fold API VanillaIceCream - Graphics backend: gfxstream
INFO - Emulator: Pixel Fold API VanillaIceCream - Found systemPath C:\Users\chich\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\system-images\android-VanillaIceCream\google_apis_playstore\x86_64\
INFO - Emulator: Pixel Fold API VanillaIceCream - Process finished with exit code -1073741515 (0xC0000135)
WARN - Emulator: Pixel Fold API VanillaIceCream - Emulator terminated with exit code -1073741515
INFO - #c.i.w.i.i.j.s.JpsGlobalModelSynchronizerImpl - Loading global entities com.intellij.platform.workspace.jps.entities.SdkEntity from files
INFO - #c.i.w.i.i.j.s.JpsGlobalModelSynchronizerImpl - Loading global entities com.intellij.platform.workspace.jps.entities.LibraryEntity from files
INFO - #c.i.w.i.i.EntitiesOrphanageImpl - Update orphanage. 0 modules added
INFO - #c.i.w.i.i.WorkspaceModelImpl - Project model updated to version 6 in 0 ms: Sync global entities with project: assisted_voice
INFO - #c.i.w.i.i.GlobalWorkspaceModel - Global model updated to version 2 in 0 ms: Sync global entities with state
WARN - #com.android.sdklib.deviceprovisioner.DeviceAction - The emulator process for AVD Pixel_Fold_API_VanillaIceCream has terminated.
com.android.tools.idea.avdmanager.EmulatorConnectionListener$EmulatorTerminatedException: The emulator process for AVD Pixel_Fold_API_VanillaIceCream has terminated.
    at com.android.tools.idea.avdmanager.EmulatorConnectionListener$WaitForEmulatorTask.run(EmulatorConnectionListener.java:93)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.RwLockHolder$executeOnPooledThread$1.run(RwLockHolder.kt:154)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:702)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:699)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1.run(Executors.java:699)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)

Few things I tried that I found on stackoverflow.

C:\Users\your_username\AppData\Local\Google\AndroidStudio2024.1\log\idea.log , find the logs here, which explains more in detail what caused your error. One of the solution was to find an error from here related fulkan....dll , if it was the same error, I have to create this .dll manually in system32. But this was not my case

Try Removing Android emulator option from the Android studio and try re enabling it or updating it. This didn't work, it gave me the same error.

I tried re-installing entire Android studio by clear all SDKs and cached files, since I have Downgraded windows in between, It shouldn't have effected anything since it was installed in a different drive, but this didn't help same error.



Update: Out of curiosity I gave this error logs to chat GPT and it told me to install Visual C++ redistributable as part of its 10 steps solution, luckily I decided to re-install my latest C++ redistributable and fortunately emulator started working.
redistributable
enter image description here
